# `block in num_to_s': undefined local variable or method

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to run a method that converts a digit to a string, in a different base.

I used the hint below to figure out how to convert to a different base

```
#You will want to use the %, or modulus function; this finds the remainder when you divide by a number:

(123 / 10**0) % 10 == 3 # ones place
(123 / 10**1) % 10 == 2 # tens place
(123 / 10**2) % 10 == 1 # hundreds place
```

However, when I run the script, I get the error

```
/Users/stepan/Desktop/ruby_tester.rb:33:in `block in num_to_s': undefined local variable or method `digit' for main:Object
```

But, I think I do have a local variable called digit. What am I doing wrong?

```
Digits = {
    1 => "1",
    2 => "2",
    3 => "3",
    4 => "4",
    5 => "5",
    6 => "6",
    7 => "7",
    8 => "8",
    9 => "9",
    10 => "10",
    11 => "a",
    12 => "b",
    13 => "c",
    14 => "d",
    15 => "e",
    16 => "f",
}

def num_to_s(num,base)

    highest_power = 0
    answer = " "
    while base**highest_power < num 
        highest_power += 1 
    end

    puts highest_power

    for power in 0..highest_power do 
        digit = Digits[ ((num / base**power) % base) ]
        answer.prepend(digit)
    end
    puts answer

end

num_to_s(10,2)
```

Comment: I get a completly different error: `baseconv.rb:32:in `prepend': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)`. Check the logic of your code, this means that you are looking up a non existent key in Digits.

Comment: your code mostly working for me (i had to do digit.to_s in 32th row). how exactly are you running it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 0 to your Digits hash:

```
0 => "0",
```

`(10 / 2**0) % 2` evaluates to `0` which it can't find in `Digits`, so is setting `digit` to nil.

There are other problems in your code (10 => '10' and 11 => 'a'?) and better ways to do things but this should get over this bump.

Answer (score 1):

`main:Object` errors typically fire up if you try to run code from `rails console`

just run the file with

```
$ruby /Users/stepan/Desktop/ruby_tester.rb
```

and with @Matt's advices it will be executed flawlessly